# How do I set the size of Google Maps app within my ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, gmsmapview

I started a brand new Single View project with just Google Maps SDK being integrated in it.

Right now it spans over all the screen (full-size), which I believe is the default setting. I want to reduce it so it doesn't take up space on the top bar and I also want to leave space on the bottom for my buttons. How do I do so?

Here's the only method implemented in my (single) view controller class:

```
- (void)loadView {
// Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
// coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1)Add a UIView into the ViewController where you want and set your custom size
2)set it's type to be GMSMapView in IdentityInspector
```

delcare IBOutlet in .H file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *map1;
```

.M

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285
                                                                longitude:103.848
                                                                     zoom:12];
        self.map1.camera = camera;
        self.map1.delegate=self;
        self.map1.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;
        self.map1.indoorEnabled = NO;
        self.map1.settings.myLocationButton = YES; 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.map1.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        });
}
```

check this blog http://vikrambahl.com/google-maps-ios-xcode-storyboards/

Comment: Got errors for each line: says member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union

Comment: @konyv12 add uikit header file and import GMSMapView header file

Comment: Thanks it worked. Seems like a weird solution though. Why did it remove the (void) didLoad method altogether (it was specified in the official Google Maps tutorial)?

Comment: @konyv12 if your problem is solved than please accept my answer so useful for other people

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -200) camera:camera];
```

//bottom view height eg:200 here

Answer (score 0):

To add Google map for limited part of the view controller then follow the following steps (using Storyboard):

1. Add `UIView` on existing `UIViewController`.
2. In Custome Class, add `GMSMapView` as Custome Class for that `UIView`.[image]
3. Create IBOutlet of `UIView` as mapView.

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
   ```
4. Give Height/Width or Constraint to mapView.
5. Your function will look like this:

   ```
   - (void)loadView {
   // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
   // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
     GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                       longitude:151.20
                                                            zoom:6];
     self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

     // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
     GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
     marker.title = @"Sydney";
     marker.snippet = @"Australia";
     marker.map = self.mapView;
   }
   ```