# How to resize view in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

My map show always full screen but I want for this size

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:                 22.5851                                                      longitude:88.3468                                                          zoom:16];
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400) camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;   
self.view = mapView_;
```

Comment: I never used such map views, but usually one adds the view as a subview: `[self.view addSubview:mapView_];` instead of assigning it. Does that work for you?

Comment: What is "self"?

Answer (score 0):

Add **UIView** in storyBoard And give the proper size. and from **IdentityInspector**
Give the name as GMSMapView instead of UIView.

And set the property of that UIView.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *map1;
```

and

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.5851 longitude:88.3468 zoom:16];
map1.delegate = self;
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, width, height) camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.map1 addSubview:mapView_];
```

I think This will work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784690/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-google-maps-app-within-my-viewcontroller